# Can I connect to an older gdbserver with a newer gdb?

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

Is gdb backwards compatible with older gdbserver versions? Can it look like it's working but fail silently?
In particular, I have a system with gdbserver 7.11.1 that I can't upgrade, but I only have gdb 8.1 for that target, and would rather not have to compile an older version of gdb.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the remote serial protocol used to communicate between GDB and GDBServer absolutely should be backward compatible.  If any issues do crop up, especially between something as recent as 7.11.1 and 8.1 then I think that would be considered a bug.

That said, I'm not aware of any significant testing that is done between older versions of GDBServer and newer versions of GDB, so it is possible that bugs could creep in.

I think it is unlikely that it would appear that things are working when really they aren't, and so you get false positives.

Of course you should expect that some newer features might not work at all (I don't have any idea what has changed in the GDBServer <-> GDB relationship since 7.11.1) but these should fail gracefully.